wiki.nginx.org links are broken
wiki.nginx.org  is currently broken and there are about 1.4k posts linking the domain. Some of these are direct references (which need to be fixed). Others are from snippets of configuration files which link back to the domain in comments.
I think fixing the latter might be less useful, and I'm unsure of local conventions for this sort of thing. On the other hand, it makes the cleanup easier if we fix them all.
A quick check suggests nginx.org hosts the replacement documentation - but with a different URL format.
wiki.nginx.org had the format http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location
ngnix.org has the format https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location
As such, in addition to altering the domain and path, we'd need to prefix the page name with ngx_
What would be the 'best' way to get these links updated?

A remark on a(n even more) meta level: tooling for bulk fixing of broken links would be a useful thing for us to have in general (and have some codified principles and process around, like we do for e.g. tag burnination), and is something we community members are in principle able to build ourselves without needing staff support. Perhaps we should!

There's a tool for this that works in some cases - especially on a one to one fix. That feels like the ideal outcome here.  There's also often processes for fixing things by the community. I'm not an SO regular here though, so I don't want to impose - I'll stick to defining the problem, and abiding by what folks more familiar with the site feel is the best way to deal. This is the process, well the beginning anyway

if we were to discuss a tool: I think it should list in a tabular format (so everything is easy to eyeball), all the found instances, results of applying the set of rewrite rules (regexps? javascript?), allow manual editing, have a manually triggered HTTP GET/HEAD result code test (per instance and for all instances), allow checking/unchecking of instances for inclusion in the actual application of the revision, support pagination/piecemeal. and it'd be a good idea to make sure it's applying the patches/edits safely. and it should not fall on its face if a post contains multiple instances.

A few notes about nginx documentation. 1. Instead of links like https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location, pointing to specific directive or variable, it is better to use a special short form https://nginx.org/r/location - in case the current link gets changed this one should redirect to the correct new one. 2. Old wiki articles can be referenced via archived nginx wiki GitHub repository: https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-wiki

Is there any assertion that the contents at the point in time authors referenced the wiki URL matches the contents found via the new URL?

I did a casual check on 4-5 links, and it seems to be similar. I've not gone through all 1.4kish posts to check.
